# R' Alexander bar R' Shlomo, "hevio likvurah"?

Tags: history, names

There is the following name in "Shemos HaTzaddikim":

> ר' אלכסנדר בר' שלמה, הביאו לקבורה

I don't understand what this means. To my understanding, הביאו לקבורה would be "he went to the grave", but that seems strange. What's the deal with this name?

I understand this may be closed as being about Jews and Judaism, but I was interested if I did translate correctly, then what is the story behind this?

Comment: הביאו doesn't mean he went. Heiviu is they brought, and hevio is he brought him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an extract from the [Wikipedia article on Rabbi Meir of Rothenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg).

> The Maharam of Rothenburg, Rabbi Meir, was born between 1215 and 1220
>   in Worms.  After the death of his father in 1281, he settled in Worms.
>   In 1286, King Rudolf I instituted a new persecution of the Jews,
>   declaring them servi camerae ("serfs of the treasury"), which had the
>   effect of negating their political freedoms. Along with many others,
>   Meir left Germany with family and followers, but was captured in the
>   mountains of Lombardy having been recognized by a baptized Jew named
>   Kneppe, and imprisoned in a fortress near Ensisheim in Alsace.
>   Tradition has it that a large ransom of 23,000 marks silver was raised
>   for him (by the Rosh), but Rabbi Meir refused it, for fear of
>   encouraging the imprisonment of other rabbis. He ruled on his own
>   abduction in light of Talmudic law. He died in prison after seven
>   years. Fourteen years after his death a ransom was paid for his body
>   by **Alexander ben Salomon Wimpfen**, who was subsequently laid to rest
>   beside the Maharam in the Jewish cemetery of Worms.

The reference you found  to 
אלכסנדר בר שלמה  refers to the fact that it was he who brought the Maharam to be buried and that's why it says 
הביאו לקבורה .